# PHP - cURL Specifying a custom Content-Type

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to do a cURL in PHP to an API that has a custom Content-Type response type option called "application/qhal+json". It returns a sort of JSON that's abstracted a bit for custom use.

What I'm using:

```php
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: applcation/qhal+json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

However the response is always coming back as 'application/json' content type. Is it not possible to specify a custom content-type? Does anyone have any ideas on why the response isn't being returned in the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the GET-request with an Accept Header:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/hal+json'));`

---

The `Accept` header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a response, which will include a `Content-Type` header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is.

HTTP requests can also contain `Content-Type` headers. This header indicates which type of content is send to the server by a POST or PUT request.